# Increasing the size of list in python

Tags: python, list

The below program gives the error IndexError: list index out of range

```
newlist=[2,3,1,5,6,123,436,124,223.......,213,213,213,56,2387567,3241,2136]   
# total 5600 values seprated by commas in the above list

emptylist = []
for values in newlist:
          convstr = str(values)
          convstr = convstr.split(",")
          emptylist.extend(convstr)

k=0
for i in range(5600):
    for j in range(0,4):
        print(i,j,emptylist[k])
        k=k+1
```

But when i used a same program now with newlist contains 1000 values,it works

```
newlist=[2,3,1,5,6,123,436,124,223.......,213]  
 # total 1000 values seprated by commas in the above list

emptylist = []
for values in newlist:
          convstr = str(values)
          convstr = convstr.split(",")
          emptylist.extend(convstr)

k=0
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(0,4):
        print(i,j,emptylist[k])
        k=k+1
```

so why it is not working with 5600 values shows index out of range but it is working with 1000 values ?

TRIED Using Len of the list also it doesn't works

Comment: `print(len(emptylist))`

Comment: why don't you run on the len of the list?instead of the number of variable you assume there is in it

Comment: tried using length of the list also not working @Green

Comment: neither of these two codes work, you are incrementing the index `k` beyond the length of the list because of the second for loop - `k` goes from 0 to 22400 (5600 * 4)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of 5600 elements. You transform them into strings which does not increase its number. you iterate 5600 times, in each iteration you increase `k` 4 times by 1 and you index into your list using `k` - result: index error

```
newlist=[2,3,1,5,6,123,436,124,223.......,213,213,213,56,2387567,3241,2136]   
# total 5600 values seprated by commas in the above list

emptylist = []
for values in newlist:
    convstr = str(values)  # values is ONE number, its string is also one number
    convstr = convstr.split(",")   # there are no , in numbers but you get a [number]
    emptylist.extend(convstr)      # this adds the string of a int to the list

k=0  # you index by k
for i in range(5600):  # you do this 5600  times
    for j in range(0,4):  # your print AND INCREASE k 4 times
        print(i,j,emptylist[k])
        k=k+1             # after about 5600 / 4 iterations of the loop your k is 
                          # larger then the amount in your list
```